# Autoloader Functions error

Tags: php, autoloader

I have always used includes if I have wanted to bring in a class I have never used the autoloader function.  When I use the function for some reason I continue to get the error.

> " Warning: include_once(classes/user.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/mjcrawle/phpfiles/preprod/test/index.php on line 6 Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'classes/user.class.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/mjcrawle/phpfiles/preprod/test/index.php on line 6 Fatal error: Class 'User' not found in /home/mjcrawle/phpfiles/preprod/test/index.php on line 42"

This is what my php include looks like.

```
require_once('classes/ registereduser.class.php');
```

This is my autoloader that I am unable to get working.  The first letter in my class is a cap that is why I am using string to lower.

```
function autoloader($class){
     include_once('classes/'.strtolower($class).'.class.php');
     }
```

spl_autoload_register(autoloader);

I could use some help on what am I getting wrong on this I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips :
- the directory "classes" is not in your include path. Since php will search there for autoload, you get what is wrong...
- add the classes directory to your include path using set_include_path function.

I can't elaborate because i'm using my phone and its keyboard is a pain.

Comment: how do you use the set_include_path function?  I am not familar with that function.

Comment: A quick tour to the php documentation --> http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php